# jQuery, :first on the list, but not first at all

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list generated by foreach:

```
<div class="rowClass">
  <div>
    <input class="MagicButton" value="click to show hidden values in row"/>
  </div>
   <div class="hiddenValues"></div>
</div>
```

Then I use jQuery to make hiddenValues visible:

```
$(".MagicButton").click(function () {
        $(".hiddenValues:first").slideDown("slow");
});
```

The problem is, when I use this on any row it happens only in first one. Without ":first" it works on all the rows. What can I do to make it happen only on the row I'm working on?

Edit: Button to be clicked is in another div, so it is still not working.
Edit2: The solution is:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().find(".HiddenValues").slideDown("slow");
```

Each parent() jumps higher in div's tree to finally search for .hiddenValues inside rowClass.
Thanks for everything! You made me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".MagicButton").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".hiddenValues").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this syntax

```
$(".MagicButton").click(function () {
     $(this).parent().find('.hiddenValues').slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: The first is fragile, small changes in structure will break it. The second is much more robust.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am aware of it.. hence I pointed out that it works only for current html.. I will remove it.. thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to make it happen only on the row I'm working on?

Use `this` in your event handler and use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to get the sibling element:

```
$(".MagicButton").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".hiddenValues").slideDown("slow");
});
```

`this` will refer to the specific `.MagicButton` related to the event. `.hiddeValues` is a sibling element (child of the same parent).